# Patching an API using Python Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

This test is giving me unusual problems:

Slightly simplified version of my test:

```
def test_credit_create_view(self):
    """ Can we create cards? """
    card_data = {'creditcard_data': 'blah blah blah'}
    with patch('apps.users.forms.CustomerAccount.psigate') as psigate:
        info = MagicMock()
        info.CardInfo.SerialNo = 42
        create = MagicMock(return_value=info)
        psigate.credit.return_value = create
        self.client.post('/make-creditcard-now', card_data)
```

The call I'm trying to mock looks like this:

```
psigate.credit().create().CardInfo.SerialNo
```

In the test, that call just returns a MagicMock object.

If I just look at the last three nodes in that call, I get the correct result:

```
create().CardInfo.SerialNo
```

returns 42

Why doesn't the full call to 'psigate.credit().create().CardInfo.SerialNo' return 42?

Comment: What is CardInfo supposed to be? A class? If so you can check out [PropertyMock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock)

Comment: CardInfo is an lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement. I have to admit I'm confused as to when PropertyMock should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the return value of psigate.credit to create, meaning psigate.credit() is your mocked 'create', NOT psigate.credit().create. This would work as expected if you called psigate.credit()() instead.

When you call psigate.credit().create() you're dynamically creating a new MagicMock object, not calling the one you defined.

Comment: Took another look at the mock docs. You can set the attributes on the return_value in one go. The following works: psigate.credit.return_value.create.return_value.CardInfo.SerialNo = 42